# How to use getReturns with the Yahoo finance API

Tags: r, yahoo-finance, yahoo-api

I have problems with R package `getReturns`. I have encountered this error since 17th May:

> Warning in file(file, "rt") :
>         cannot open URL 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&a=4&b=28&c=2014&d=4&e=27&f=2017&g=w&ignore=.csv': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'

It looks like that `ichart` API did not run anymore. Can anyone help me with this issue? Does someone know how to fix it? I have encountered the same issue with the `quantmod` R package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow my an earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44018600/error-in-getsymbols-function-usage-in-rhttps/44021834#44021834), which might help you.

I tried :

```
library(quantmod)
# Create an object containing the Pfizer ticker symbol
symbol <- "PFE"    
# Use getSymbols to import the data
getSymbols(symbol, src="yahoo", auto.assign=T) 
# because src='google' throws error, yahoo was used, and even that is down
```

When I tried other source, it worked:

```
# "quantmod::oanda.currencies" contains a list of currencies provided by Oanda.com
currency_pair <- "GBP/CAD"    
# Load British Pound to Canadian Dollar exchange rate data
getSymbols(currency_pair, src="oanda")
str(GBPCAD)
```

It seems there are issues with google and yahoo while we use quantmod pkg.

I will suggest you to use 'Quandl' instead. Plz goto Quandl website, register for free and create API key, and then copy it in below:

```
# Install Quandl
install.packages("Quandl")
# or from github
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("quandl/quandl-r")

# Load the Quandl package
library(Quandl)

# use API for full access
Quandl.api_key("xxxxxx")

# Download APPLE stock data
mydata = Quandl::Quandl.datatable("ZACKS/FC", ticker="AAPL")
```

For HDFC at BSE, you can use:

```
hdfc = Quandl("BSE/BOM500180")
```

for more details:

```
https://www.quandl.com/data/BSE-Bombay-Stock-Exchange?keyword=HDFC
```

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered this problem as well. Yahoo! has taken down ichart and the open-source libraries that rely on it are now broken. Yahoo! also has no plans to introduce a replacement. For more information, see this post on Yahoo!'s [Forums](https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Yahoo-Finance-help/Is-Yahoo-Finance-API-broken/td-p/250503).

Answer (score 2):

I switched to eodhistoricaldata.com after Yahoo failed, several weeks ago I found good [alternative](https://eodhistoricaldata.com/) with an API very similar to Yahoo Finance.

Basically, for almost all R scripts I use I just changed this:

```
URL <- paste0("ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=", symbols[i])
```

to:

```
URL <- paste0("eodhistoricaldata.com/api/table.csv?s=", symbols[i])
```

Then add an API key and it will work in the same way as before. I saved a lot of time for my R scripts on it.