# Problems with getSymbols.yahoo

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to analyze a time series about Tether USD (a crypto) from yahoo finance.
I downloaded the information and I have the following code:

```
###librarys
library("tseries")
library("quantmod")
library("timeSeries")

#read data
path <- file.path("Bases de datos")
CRYPTO <- file.path(path, "USDT-USD.csv") #original file name
USDT <- read.csv(CRYPTO)

#time serie
usdt_ts <- get.hist.quote(instrument = 'USDT',start = "2018-01-01",end = "2021-12-31",quote = c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close","Adjusted", "Vol"),compression = "d")
```

but appear the next error :

```
Warning: USDT download failed; trying again.
Error in getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = "USDT", env = <environment>, verbose = FALSE,  : 
  Unable to import “USDT”.
argument "conn" is missing, with no default
```

i'm trying with this solution, but it's does'nt work
[Error in getSymbols function usage in R(https)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44018600/error-in-getsymbols-function-usage-in-rhttps)

any ideas to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo finance doesn't recognize USDT as a valid ticker. If  you want to download this data you need to use "USDT-USD".

```
USDT <- getSymbols("USDT-USD",start = "2018-01-01",end = "2021-12-31", auto.assign = F)

head(USDT)
           USDT-USD.Open USDT-USD.High USDT-USD.Low USDT-USD.Close USDT-USD.Volume USDT-USD.Adjusted
2017-11-09       1.01087       1.01327     0.996515        1.00818       358188000           1.00818
2017-11-10       1.00650       1.02423     0.995486        1.00601       756446016           1.00601
2017-11-11       1.00598       1.02621     0.995799        1.00899       746227968           1.00899
2017-11-12       1.00602       1.10591     0.967601        1.01247      1466060032           1.01247
2017-11-13       1.00448       1.02929     0.975103        1.00935       767884032           1.00935
2017-11-14       1.00524       1.01343     0.996898        1.00683       429857984           1.00683
```